# Regex Visual Studio One Specific Character

Tags: regex, visual-studio, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to validate a text box in Visual Studio to be either the character M or F. I have a few other validations with regex set in a similar fashion which are all working correctly. However, with this one, it still allows me to use ANY letter in the text box. What is wrong with this code?

```
public static bool IsGender(string gender)
{
    bool validGender = true;
    string _genderRegEx = @"^\:|m|M|f|F|$";
    if ((!Regex.Match(gender, _genderRegEx).Success))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Gender must be either M or F.");
        validGender = false;
    }
    return validGender;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. You have:

```
@"^\:|m|M|f|F|$"
```

The `|` symbols mean boolean `OR`. Because you don't have any parentheses to group parts of your regex, the `^` only goes with `\:`, and the `$` is by itself. As a result, your regex matches any of the following:

- The start of the string (`^`) plus `:`
- `m` or `M`
- `f` or `F`
- **the end of the string (`$`).**

Every string has an ending, so every string matches.

A correct regex would be:

```
@"^[mMfF]$"
```

This matches the start of the string (`^`), followed by exactly one of `m`, `M`, `f`, or `F`, followed by the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Will mark correct when the time expires.